# Triple image using CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-selectors, media-queries

I am trying to an image if the width of a screen is larger than 600px such that I have the same the image thrice side by side. If the screen (device-width) is less than `600px`, the single image should be displayed.

```
<div class="gallery" style="border: 3px solid green;">
    <figure class="photo tripled">
        <img src="images/rocket1.jpg" alt="Great Rocket" width="100%">
        <figcaption>Rocket 1 (tripled)</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .gallery > .tripled {
        font-size: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 24%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include 2 extra instances of the image that are not displayed by default and use your media query to display them and adjust the original image's width for screen widths above 600px.

```css
.tripleImg {
    display:none;
}
    
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .tripled {
        font-size: 0;
    }
    .firstImg {
      width: 33.3%;
    }
    .tripleImg {
      display:inline;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery" style="border: 3px solid green;">
    <figure class="photo tripled">
        <img class='firstImg' src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a31c765009a1a075823bf1e217b5dae9?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Great Rocket" width="100%">
        <img class='tripleImg' src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a31c765009a1a075823bf1e217b5dae9?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Great Rocket" width="33.3%">
        <img class='tripleImg' src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a31c765009a1a075823bf1e217b5dae9?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Great Rocket" width="33.3%">
        <figcaption>Rocket 1 (tripled)</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```